# How do I switch debugging mode back and forth between a device and the simulator in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, console, xcode5

So I run an app on my device and then I run it on the simulator. Both are running and Xcode recognizes this, but I only receive debug info in the console from the most recently run one (in this case, the simulator). How do I switch the console output to be from the device or simulator so I can switch back and forth between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is select the other "device" in the left side of the debugging pane in Xcode. Then you will see the console for that device.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I missed that.